# PushViewController causing NullReferenceException Xamarin

Tags: c#, xamarin

Inside the app delegate I have declared

```
ViewController1 vc = new ViewController1 ();
Window.RootViewController = vc;
```

I have the class

```
public partial class ViewController1 : UIViewController
```

And when a button is pressed inside this `ViewController1`, I want to push another view controller:

```
ViewController2 vc = new ViewController2();
This.NavigationController.PushViewController(vc, false);
```

I am getting this error when I try to push ViewController2:

> System.NullReferenceException. Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object

Inside my `ViewController2` 
the class is defined with the header:

```
public partial class ViewController2 : UIViewController
```

Is it because of the UIViewController header. If so, how do I go about fixing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have to explicitly set your ViewController inside of a NavigationController, otherwise the NavigationController property will be null.

```
ViewController1 vc = new ViewController1 ();
Window.RootViewController = new UINavigationController(vc);
```